# Chef bootstrapping error : ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, devops, chef-infra

I am using GCP debian server to learn chef. I have successfully install chef in the workstation. But while connecting nodes using bootstrap process i am getting below error : warn: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout WARN: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user root@10.182.0.24>) ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established Command i used is : knife bootstrap  -U root --sudo -i  -N node1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, had a password including special characters and after I put the pass in single quotes the bootstrap worked.